# Set volume of both earpieces individually - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I’m trying to set the volume of both earpieces (left and right earpiece) individually?

I looked into it and found out that it is possible in android native. There is MediaPlayer class in android native that has setVolume method which takes two parameters (one for left earpiece volume and other one for right)

Is there any library available for such function in flutter?

This package does have setVolume method but it takes only parameters (so can’t set the volume for earpieces individually)

https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers

Any help would be appreciated